# Invoking a member function on each object in a list that mutates the list the objects are in

Tags: c++, list, object, stl

How do you manage a situation where objects inside a `std::list` need to move their position in, or even remove themselves from that list, while you are iterating over that list?

A complicated example follows.

You have an *ordered* `list` of objects.

```
list< Object* > objects ;
```

You have a loop that iterates over each

```
for( list< Object* >::iterator iter = objects.begin() ; iter != objects.end() ; ++iter )
{
    // call "move()" on each
    (*iter)->move() ;
}
```

Now here's the catch.  `Object::move()` sometimes **reorders the list**, the very list that we are iterating on with the loop above.

I'm not sure how to engineer this.  How can I write and invoke a member function `Object::move()` that *possibly* re-orders the list every time you call it, and iterate over each element in the `objects` list, invoking `Object::move()` on each `Object` in the `list`?

Comment: Sounds like a design issue. Why do the objects need to know they are in a list? Can't something else do the reordering?

Comment: Because it was convenient for objects to move themselves, since they know where they should be moved __to__ in the list.

Comment: You could make your `move()` return the iterator following the last moved element, just like `std::list::erase()` does.

Comment: @bobobobo - why do they know this?  Seems to me you've got an object that has too many responsibilities and knows too much.  These responsibilities should be split out among objects so that the composition of them equals the behavior you want.

Comment: The objects _do_ know a lot about their container.  Perhaps you're right, and that logic should be moved to the container class.

Comment: @jrok Actually that is a good suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Holistically.

Putting a member in the contained object that knows about and manipulates the container is almost universally a bad design choice.  You want container->contained but not contained->container.

Your sorting routine is going to have to be just that, a sorting routine that uses whatever rules "move" would otherwise use to decide when to swap things around.  You are basically ordering your list by some condition when you call "move" over all its elements, so you just change this idea of elements moving themselves to them being moved by something that knows how they need to be ordered.  When you do this of course that condition can be different for different client needs.

Answer (score 0):

I figured I could remember *who* **should** be next, before calling `move()`, and always use that.

```
for( list< Object* >::iterator iter = objects.begin() ; iter != objects.end() ; )
{
    // call "move()" on each
    list< Object* >::iterator shouldBeNext = iter ;
    ++shouldBeNext ;

    (*iter)->move() ;

    iter = shouldBeNext ;
}
```

I can set a `moved` flag inside each `object` before calling this loop to `false`, and when `Object::move` is called, that flag is switched to true.  That way, if the object is moved earlier in the list (it is no matter), and if the object is moved late in the list it will not be asked to `::move` twice.  Also this makes sure that *every* object is asked to move at least once, and eliminates the scenario where objects would be skipped, due to `iter` moving far down the list and `++iter` thus skipping many elements.

Comment: Sounds dubious to me to be honest.  I think you're asking for trouble here.